# GET , will not receive my POST ? PHP

Tags: php, html, dynamic

I have created a dynamic signature maker for my online game.
You can create the sig manually via

http://pernix-rsps.com/sig/pcard.php?user=usernamehere
I tried to make a userbox and submit , so that people does not have to visit

http://pernix-rsps.com/sig/pcard.php?user=USERNAME

and edit it, i want it to create the link for them upon entering username

my code for the username box

```
    <center>



<form name="sig" id="sig" method="get" action="pcard.php">
<table border="0">
<tr><td colspan="2"><?php echo isset($_GET["user"])?$_GET["user"]:"";?> </td></tr>
<tr><td width="30">Username</td><td width="249"><input name="username" type="text" id="username" width="150px" placeholder="Username" /> </td></tr>

<tr><td></td><td><input name="btnsubmit" type="submit" id="btnsubmit" title="create sig" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>

            </center>
```

And then pcard.php

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['user'])) {
        $image_path = "img/saved_cards/".$_GET['user'].".png";
        if (file_exists($image_path)) {
            if (time() < filemtime($image_path) + 300) { // every 5 minutes ?
                pullFromCache($image_path);
                exit;
            }
        }
        generate();
    }

    function pullFromCache($image_path) {
        header("Content-type: image/png");
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($image_path);
        imagepng($image);
    }

    function generate() {

        $DB_HOST = "localhost";
        $DB_USER = "";
        $DB_PASS = "";
        $DB_NAME = "";

        $user = clean($_GET['user']);
        $con = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME) or die($con->error);
        $res = $con->query("SELECT * FROM hs_users WHERE username='$user'");

        if($res->num_rows > 0) {
            header("Content-type: image/png");
            getSig($res->fetch_assoc());
        } else {
            header("Content-type: image/png");
            $image = imagecreatefrompng('./img/sigbg.png');
            $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
            imagestring($image, 3, 251, 10, 'Invalid User', $color);
            imagepng($image);
        }
    }
    function getSig($row) {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng('./img/sigbg.png');

        $color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
        $yellow = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 0);

        $total = getTotalLevel($row);
        $combat = getCombatLevel($row);
        imagestring($image, 5, 250, 10, ''.$row['username'].'', $yellow);
        imagestring($image, 2, 250, 26, 'Exp: '.number_format($row['overall_xp']).'', $color);
        imagestring($image, 2, 250, 39, 'Total: '.number_format($total).'', $color);
        imagestring($image, 2, 250, 51, 'Pernix-Rsps.com ', $color);        
        $array = array("Attack", "Defence", "Strength", "hitpoints", "Range", "Prayer", "Magic", "Cooking", "Woodcutting", "Fletching", "Fishing", "Firemaking", "Crafting", "Smithing", "Mining", "Herblore", "Agility", "Thieving", "Slayer", "Farming", "Runecrafting", "Hunter", "pk", "Summoning", "Dungeoneering");

        $baseX = 28;
        $baseY = 4;

        foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
            imagestring($image, 2, $baseX, $baseY, ''.getRealLevel($row[''.strtolower($array[$i]).'_xp'], strtolower($array[$i])).'', $color);
            $baseY += 15;
            if ($baseY > 64) {
                $baseY = 4;
                $baseX += 45;
            }
        }
        ImagePNG($image, "img/saved_cards/".$row['username'].".png");
        imagepng($image);
    }



    function getTotalLevel($row) {
        $total = 0;
        $array = array("Attack", "Defence", "Strength", "Hitpoints", "Range", "Prayer", "Magic", "Cooking", "Woodcutting", "Fletching", "Fishing", "Firemaking", "Crafting", "Smithing", "Mining", "Herblore", "Agility", "Thieving", "Slayer", "Farming", "Runecrafting", "Hunter", "pk", "Summoning", "Dungeoneering");
        foreach ($array as $i => $value) {
            $skillName = strtolower($array[$i]);
            $total += getRealLevel($row[$skillName.'_xp'], strtolower($skillName));
        }
        return $total;
    }

    function getLevel($exp) {
        $points = 0;
        $output = 0;
        for ($lvl = 1; $lvl <= 99; $lvl++) {
            $points += floor($lvl + 300.0 * pow(2.0, $lvl / 7.0));
            $output = (int) floor($points / 4);
            if (($output - 1) >= $exp) {
                return $lvl;
            }
        }
        return 99;
    }

    function getRealLevel($exp, $skill) {
        $points = 0;
        $output = 0;
        $skillId = $skill == "dungeoneering" ? 1 : 0;
        for ($lvl = 1; $lvl <= ($skillId == 1 ? 120 : 99); $lvl++) {
            $points += floor($lvl + 300.0 * pow(2.0, $lvl / 7.0));
            $output = (int) floor($points / 4);
            if (($output - 1) >= $exp) {
                return $lvl;
            }
        }
        return ($skillId == 1 ? 120 : 99);
    }

    function getDungLevel($exp) {
        $points = 0;
        $output = 0;
        for ($lvl = 1; $lvl <= 120; $lvl++) {
            $points += floor($lvl + 300.0 * pow(2.0, $lvl / 7.0));
            $output = (int) floor($points / 4);
            if (($output - 1) >= $exp) {
                return $lvl;
            }
        }
        return 120;
    }

    function clean($string) {
        return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 \-]/', '', $string);
    }

    function getCombatLevel($row) {
        $attack = getLevel($row['attack_xp']);
        $defence = getLevel($row['defence_xp']);
        $strength = getLevel($row['strength_xp']);
        $hp = getLevel($row['hitpoints_xp']);
        $prayer = getLevel($row['prayer_xp']);
        $ranged = getLevel($row['range_xp']);
        $magic = getLevel($row['magic_xp']);
        $combatLevel = (int) (($defence + $hp + floor($prayer / 2)) * 0.25) + 1;
        $melee = ($attack + $strength) * 0.325;
        $ranger = floor($ranged * 1.5) * 0.325;
        $mage = floor($magic * 1.5) * 0.325;

        if ($melee >= $ranger && $melee >= $mage) {
            $combatLevel += $melee;
        } else if ($ranger >= $melee && $ranger >= $mage) {
            $combatLevel += $ranger;
        } else if ($mage >= $melee && $mage >= $ranger) {
            $combatLevel += $mage;
        }
        return (int)$combatLevel;
    }

?>
```

upon entering and submiting the username in the box, it just takes you to the pcard.php without image being made

any ideas

Comment: Your code is highly insecure! Never trust GET or POST parameters blindly. It is very very easy to inject HTML and javascript in yourpages, check google for "XSS". And by the way read also about SQL injection.

Comment: You're trying to copy runescape? Sure looks like it.

Comment: http://pernix-rsps.com/sig/pcard.php?username=danny&btnsubmit=Submit+Query

needs to be 
http://pernix-rsps.com/sig/pcard.php?user=danny

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong fieldname in your PHP. In your form you use the fieldname `username`:

```
<input name="username" ... />
```

And in your PHP you try to get `GET['user']`. Change that in `GET['username']` and everything should work (the getting the value part that is ;)).

Comment: Also can I reccomend to the OP of this question that if you post another question to SoF, don't include the code you know works by example. Example if your image generation code works exactly as you want it (See Unit Testing) then just say it does. People will be able to figure out from reading your first 20 something lines if your error is in the code that you didn't include versus the code you did. Sometimes it will work against you but here it's a fairly good place to ignore the fluff.

Also might I add, your code is really bad and I recommend you google OOP in PHP. Sorry to be rude.

Comment: @sven , i followed your above once i submit the form its give this

pcard.php?username=danny&btnsubmit=Submit+Query

its ment to be

pcard.php?user=danny

Comment: @user3729972 Then just change the fieldname to `user` in your HTML.. `<input name="user" ... />`, the field's name is the key in your `GET` array.